# Changing mapping field type elasticsearch 1.7

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have to change type of price field in mapping from string to float.
when i am trying this

`curl -XPUT http://52.73.2.239:9200/products/_mapping/product -d '{
"properties":{
    "productOnly.price":{
         "type" : "float"
         }
    }
}'`

but nothing changes.
here is mapping of my data

`"properties" : {
      //I some props and other objects. productOnly is nested object
      "productOnly" : {
         "properties" : {
             "bonus" : {
                 "type" : "string"
             },
             "price" : {
                 "type" : "string"
            }
       }
   }
}`

Comment: You [cannot do that](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings), you need to either create another field with the `float` type and populate it, or wipe your index, recreate it and re-populate it.

Comment: but can i create mapping before adding data to my index?

Comment: Yes, but once you have given a certain type to your field you cannot change it. You have to delete the index and recreate it with the new type.

Comment: can you explain how can i create my mapping before loading data to my index?

Comment: When i removed index and tried to create a mapping  ES throws an error

        `"error": "IndexMissingException[[products] missing]",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a mapping has been created, you [cannot change it](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings) (you can but only for very special cases explained in the previous link).

So what you have to do is to delete your index...

```
curl -XDELETE http://52.73.2.239:9200/products
```

... and recreate it with the proper mapping:

```
curl -XPUT http://52.73.2.239:9200/products -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        ... other properties...
        "productOnly": {
          "properties": {
            "bonus": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "price": {
              "type": "float"         <--- chance the type here
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then you can re-populate your index with some data.

Comment: I tried this in postman app
and i get an error


`   "error": "InvalidIndexNameException[[products  -d] Invalid index name [products  -d], must not contain the following characters [\\, /, *, ?, \", <, >, |,  , ,]]",
`

Comment: That's a curl command, you cannot copy/paste that in postman. The URL you need to use in Postman is simply `http://52.73.2.239:9200/products`, i.e. no `-d ...`